# Cannot Maintain Firestore RecyclerView State On Back Navigation

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have a Fragment that contains a Recylcerview. This RecyclerView is populated using the Firebase FirestoreUI.

Below is the code for my RecyclerView, which I call in .onStart() to listen to changes:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mRecyclerViewState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(RECYCLERVIEW_STATE);
        }
        mRecyclerview = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        mPollHolderArray = new ArrayList<>();
        mRecyclerview.getItemAnimator().setChangeDuration(0);


        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        //TODO: Detertmine if necessary since ordering is now different in Firebase
        mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

        mFloatingActionAdd = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myFAB);
        mFloatingActionAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent I = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), CreateActivity.class);
                startActivity(I);
            }
        });


        mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        if (mRecyclerViewState != null){
            mLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(mRecyclerViewState);
        }


        if (mFirestoreAdaper == null) {
            Query queryStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                    .collection(POLLS_LABEL)
                    .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
            //Cloud Firestore does not have any ordering; must implement a timestampe to order sequentially

            FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Poll> storeOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Poll>()
                    .setQuery(queryStore, Poll.class)
                    .build();
            mFirestoreAdaper = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Poll, PollHolder>(storeOptions) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PollHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull Poll model) {
                    holder.mPollQuestion.setText(model.getQuestion());
                    String voteCount = String.valueOf(model.getVote_count());
                    //TODO: Investigate formatting of vote count for thousands
                    holder.mVoteCount.setText(voteCount);
                    Picasso.get()
                            .load(model.getImage_URL())
                            .fit()
                            .into(holder.mPollImage);
                    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent toClickedPoll = new Intent(getActivity(), PollHostActivity.class);
                            String recyclerPosition = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId();
                            Log.v("Firestore ID", recyclerPosition);
                            toClickedPoll.putExtra("POLL_ID", recyclerPosition);
                            startActivity(toClickedPoll);

                        }
                    });
                }


                @Override
                public PollHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.latest_item, parent, false);
                    return new PollHolder(v);
                }


            };
            mRecyclerview.setAdapter(mFirestoreAdaper);
        }
    }
```

When I navigate to another Fragment (onClick of the RecyclerView) and then back to the Fragment containing this RecyclerView, I expect to be able to maintain the position that was clicked. However, this is not occurring. Below is the code I have tried to save the state, it is simply reverting back to the top item of the RecyclerView:

```
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mRecyclerViewState = mLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();
    outState.putParcelable(RECYCLERVIEW_STATE, mRecyclerViewState);

}
```

EDIT: The original Fragment is part of a ViewPager (I am testing it right now on the NewFragment):

```
    public class SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new TrendingFragment();
            case 1:
                return new FollowingFragment();
            case 2:
                return new NewFragment();
            default:
                return new TrendingFragment();
        }
    }
```

Comment: show the fragment transition code

Comment: it might happen you are loading a fresh fragment on every click

Comment: What exact code do you need to see? Thanks for the help

Comment: the code you use to transit from one fragment to another

Comment: It is in the holder, there is a click Listener

Comment: so does your fragment change at all or you just go to an activity and come back to it ?

Comment: I simply navigate to a new Activity, then come back

Comment: ok wait for a min

Comment: I also updated to show that the original Fragment is part of a ViewPager

Comment: if you have a look at the life cycle of a fragment => https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment

it says onStart() makes the fragment visible to the user (based on its containing activity being started).

Comment: so i think you data rendering code must move to onViewCreated

Comment: Which code though? I always thought Firebase data should be registered in onStart()

Comment: but that function runs before the instance state is set so every time it runs the value of instate stae is null and starts the recyclerviw form 0 state imean as a freash recyclerview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're setting new adapter in `onStart`, and that happens whenever you resume the fragment, either from previous screen or background.

You don't need all these logics to help to remember the position, you just have to initialise and set your adapter in the right place within the lifecycle.

In your fragment, set your adapter in `onViewCreated` instead of `onStart`:

```
@Override public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mRecyclerview = view.findViewById(...);
    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter(...)
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.startListening();
    }
}

@Override public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    mAdapter.stopListening();
}
```

And remove all of your logics of saving and restoring position (`onSaveInstanceState`, `scrollToPosition`, `onRestoreInstanceState`), you don't need them!

Comment: Doesn't the FirestoreRecyclerAdapter need to be initialized in onStart() so that it can subscribe to the Firebase Firestore?

Comment: @tccpg288 Nope, even though it is designed to be self-aware of lifecycle, but that doesn't mean it should be created in `onStart`.

Comment: So I should delete from .onStart()?

Comment: You should only init and set your adapter in onViewCreated, but I think you probably want to keep mAdapter.startListening in onStart, I'm not too familiar with Firebase adapter but I'm very sure that setting adapter should happen in onViewCreated.

Comment: Actually, it's safe to remove every in `onStart`, you don't need to call `mAdapter.startListening`, it is already handled in the adapter. I hope!

Comment: I have updated my code to include onViewCreated() implementation, and I am still not able to resolve. Thanks again for help, I appreciate it!

Comment: @tccpg288 You're welcome. By the way, I'd like to comment on your updated code: you should not need to restore or save recycler view state, and also do not call `onRestoreInstanceState` manually. If you can just decorate your RecyclerView and set adapter when it is null in `onViewCreated`, then you will be just fine.

Comment: Thanks, I actually moved .startListening() and .stopListening() to onViewCreated() and on onDestroyView(), and it worked! If you can update your answer, I will mark as correct

Comment: The null check really saved me. If anybody else is facing this issue, just make sure you add the null check for adapter before initializing it in `onViewCreated`